# navigator.network.connection.type always returns "unknown"

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am new to the phonegap. I am using it for WP7. I've been trying to
perform a simple test to get the connection type. I use this:

var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

```
   console.log("networkState: "+networkState);
```

But it always displays "unknown" connection. I am using the windows
phone emulator that came with SDK. Is anyone having similar issues??
Plz help..